# How to specify multiple submit handlers for multiple forms

Tags: forms

I am implementing `hook_forms` in my custom module and I don't know how to have multiple form submit handlers.

Here is my custom form function:

```
function data_retrieval_main_form()
{
    $form ['field2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Name'),
        '#default_value' => $name,
        '#maxlength' => 127,
    );

    $form ['field3'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Age'),
        '#default_value' => $age,
        '#maxlength' => 127,
    );

    $form['fileupload'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Choose Image'),
        '#type' => 'file',
    );

    $form ['submit_field'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#default_value' => 'Submit',
    );

    return $form;
}
```

Here I am implementing `hook_forms`:

```
 function hook_forms($form_id, $args) {

      $forms ['mymodule_first_form'] = array(
        'callback' => 'data_retrieval_main_form',
      );


      $forms ['mymodule_second_form'] = array(
        'callback' => 'mymodule_main_form',
        'callback arguments' => array('some parameter'),
      );

      return $forms;
    }
```

Now I previously had a single form using `hook_form` and the handler was simply like this:

```
function data_retrieval_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state)
{
// validation and submission of form 
}
```

But now that I have multiple forms, how do I have multiple submit handlers for the forms, is there a way in Drupal that checks which form is being submitted?

Comment: Might this can help : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80136/drupal-7-multiple-submit-handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a submit handler for each of your forms. Examples:

Override default handler with custom handler (new array):

```
$form['#submit'] = array('data_retrieval_form_submit');
```

Run custom handler after default (append to array):

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'data_retrieval_form_submit';
```

Run custom handler before default (prepend array):

```
array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'data_retrieval_form_submit');
```

You can add it to the `$form` array in a custom form builder function, or alter an existing form via [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

Comment: `$form['#submit']` needs to be an array...

Comment: Which function does this go into?

Comment: I've expanded on my answer.

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean, I have my form fields in my `hook_form` function, that is where I specify the submit button:  `$form ['submit_field'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#default_value' => 'Submit',
    );` so where and how can I specify which form links to which submit handler. You also mention `$forms` array but the code shows `$form` array?. Showing which function to put these in will help

Comment: It is `$form` (typo). The '#submit' key is not the same as 'submit' (or 'submit_field'), but both do belong to the `$form` array. Where? Unless you are using a hook (which I have shown), the function is one _you_ declare. In your case one of them appears to be `data_retrieval_main_form()`.

Comment: Just a note that your `data_retrieval_main_form()` function is not actually a hook, but a callback (although a hook [exists](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7)). And you have renamed the `hook_forms()` function to `whatevermymodulenameis_forms()`, correct?

Comment: Yes, I have renamed `hook_forms` to my `modulename_forms` and I think I know what you mean now but my custom form builder function won't render a submit button unless I have an explicit submit field like my previous comment, it needs an input type submit

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what any of this has to do with your submit button?

Comment: How does a form get submitted? magic? no through a submit button. So if each form has its own submit handler then it would need its own submit button no?

Comment: Of course. I don't see how that is relevant. I'm talking about a key named '#submit' that is added to the `$form` array. Not 'submit' or 'submit_field' or anything having to do with your button. (Also: I don't believe sarcasm will do you any favours here.)

Comment: So how will the form submission get triggered off?  (Sorry for the sarcasm I'm getting quite frustrated here with Drupal)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28866/discussion-between-othermachines-and-user3574492).